# Add Multiple templates in one cell in kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new in kendo-ui.I am integrating kendo-ui with angularjs.I want to show the two buttons in single cell. I dont know how can i achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="mygrid" kendo-grid k-data-source="products"   
       k-pageable='{ "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true }'
       k-columns='[
                      { "field": "ProductName", "title": "Name"}, 
                      { "field": "Supplier.SupplierName", "title": "Supplier" }, 
                      { "field": "Category.CategoryName", "title": "Category" },
                      { "template": "<button class=\"k-button\" ng-click=\"clickMe(#=ProductID#)\">Delete this item</button>", "title": "Delete" }
                  ]'
        k-sortable="true", k-groupable="true", k-filterable="true"
 >
 </div>

<div kendo-window="modal" k-title="'Title'" k-visible="false" k-modal="true">
  Product Id clicked: {{ productId }}
</div>
```

Comment: did you try by adding it in the template like template: "<button1><button2><buttonn>" ? i think it will work.

Comment: can you please tell me how can add click event on each field?

Comment: the same way you are adding to one button :)

Comment: I want to expand table on click of each field.

Comment: did you mean a child table? want to expand a child table?

Comment: use expandRow method of your grid. access your grid and then call this method with row index to expand

Comment: can you please give some source code?